# How to push object value based on the existance of another value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to push the value of a specific key into an array based on the value of another in the same object. Is this possible?

For example:

```
var goodFruit = [];

var obj = [{ status: 'good', value: 'apple' },{ status: 'bad', value: 'orange' },{ status: 'good', value: 'grape' },{ status: 'bad', value: 'lemon' }];
```

I want to then push **only** the `value` of the `status:good` into the goodFruit array so the result would look like:

```
var goodFruit = ['apple', 'grape'];
```

Comment: Shouldn't some of those identifiers be strings instead (`'good' rather than `good`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Where you were getting stuck here? Did you have trouble looping over the `obj` array? Did you have trouble retrieving properties from the elements once you had them? Did you have trouble pushing onto an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i =0;i<obj.length;i++){
 if(obj[i].status==='good'){
   goodFruit.push(obj[i].value)
 }
}
console.log(goodFruit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` and `map`:

> The **filter()** method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var obj = [{ status: 'good', value: 'apple' },{ status:'bad', value: 'orange' },{ status: 'good', value: 'grape' },{ status: 'bad', value: 'lemon' }];

var goodFruits=obj.filter(function(a){
  return a.status=='good';
}).map(function(b){
  return b.value;
});

console.log(goodFruits)
```

Or as Suggested by Ted Hopp, You can use `reduce` which is more efficient with just a one pass

> The **reduce()** method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

Comment: I think `a.status && a.status=='good'` can be simplified to just `a.status == 'good'`.

Comment: Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), this can be done with a single pass through the array.

Comment: @TedHopp Thats simply awsome

Answer (score 1):

```
obj.forEach(function(o){
if(o.status==='good'){
   goodFruit.push(o.value)
 }
})
```

Comment: It seems slightly odd that you would `forEach` for looping but not use `filter` for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for this:

```js
var obj = [
  { status: 'good', value: 'apple' },
  { status: 'bad', value: 'orange' },
  { status: 'good', value: 'grape' },
  { status: 'bad', value: 'lemon' }
];

var goodFruit = obj.reduce(
  function(result, item) {
    if (item.status === 'good') {
      result.push(item.value);
    }
    return result;
  }, []
);
alert(goodFruit);
```